# Ejecutar dos scrips al mismo tiempo en Python

Tags: python, tkinter, script

Estoy buscando una forma de ejecutar dos scrips al mismo tiempo en Python. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es lo siguiente: Una aplicación gráfica con Tkinter (muy sencilla). El problema es cuando ejecuto un comando (a través de un botón), la venta de Tkinter no responde.

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que escribí usa el modulo `threading` para ejecutar una tarea separada que duerme al programa por 3 segundos. Pero al mismo tiempo el programa de Tkinter funciona sin trabarse.

Agregar `ventana.mainloop` en tu código es importante para que mi respuesta funcione.

**IMPORTANTE**: Recuerda bloquear el botón durante la ejecución del segundo script de la misma forma que lo hago en mi código. No creo que quieras que el usuario presione muchas veces el botón y abra el script muchas veces en un solo segundo.

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
import time

def sleep():
    print("inicio funcion")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("termina funcion")
    boton["state"]='normal'
    
def callback():
    boton["state"]='disable'
    Thread(target=sleep).start()

v=Tk()

boton=Button(v, command=callback)
boton.pack()

v.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder!!!

Comment: Hola! y de nada, un placer ayudar! Te sirvió?